Why don't consensus clients have an RPC method to query the total supply of ETH (all ETH minted)?
I understand that the total supply of ETH can't be hardcoded into consensus clients because this value needs to be derived from the blockchain state to prevent tampering. To get the total supply, we would aggregate block rewards from the genesis block up to the current block and subtract any ETH that has been burned (e.g., through EIP-1559).
Given that consensus clients provide RPC methods to query individual block rewards (like the api endpoint /eth/v1/beacon/rewards/blocks/head on beacon API), why isn't there a direct eth_totalSupply RPC method in clients like Prysm? Is the absence of such a method due to the computational expense involved in continuously deriving the total supply, or are there other considerations?

Probably there wasn't enough requests to add such method. Defining a maintaining a public api requires a lot of effort. If nobody wants to maintain it then it probably wont be part of the public api.
